# multiple json objects in jquery $.post

Tags: jquery

I wanted to know if it was possible to send multiple json objects to a php file in jquery, kind of like this:

```
$.post('convert.php', [{name: 'John', font: 'arial', size: '12'},{name: 'Smith', font: 'verdana', size: '14'}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just have to construct the JSON strings first, then send them as normal post parameters.  What you have listed above is actually not JSON, but actual JS objects.  You need to convert them to a JSON string - try using the json2.js ( https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js ) to serialize your objects.  Then, just pass those JSON strings as options in your post data.

To be clear - json2.js provides the JSON.stringify() method for those browsers which do not support it natively.  The JSON.stringify() method is what you actually use to convert your JS objects into JSON strings.

Comment: jQuery converts JSON objects.

Comment: really?  I'm looking in the .ajax api docs and all I see is that it converts simple maps to name/value pairs.  Even so - if you wanted two distinct objects sent back, I'd think you would need to do something like I described.

Comment: From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/ : "Note: Because there is no universally agreed-upon specification for param strings, it is not possible to encode complex data structures using this method in a manner that works ideally across all languages supporting such input. Until such time that there is, the $.param method will remain in its current form."

Comment: I was assuming the OP would convert to an object. If I send `{ foo: [ { a: "hi" }, { b: "byte" }]}` it sends `foo[0][a]: hi` and `foo[1][b]: bye`. I guess to me that means it does what I'd expect.